# Setting up a local zookeeper and kafka using docker and wurstmeisters images

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I really have a hard time to configure my docker compose to get my kafka  running. I always get the following error on `docker-compose logs`:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners
>   from 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:': Unable to parse PLAINTEXT://kafka: to a
>   broker endpoint

I have tried all possible IP adresses and names of my machine for the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` but this does not change the situation. However this is my current docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    hostname: kafka
    restart: unless-stopped
#    links: 
#      - zookeeper:zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS=1
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS="test:1:1"
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./data:/kafka
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have stopped using wurstmeister and switched to bitnami. Here the config works just straight from the example.

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    hostname: zookeeper
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    #volumes:
    #  - ./data/zookeeper:/bitnami/zookeeper
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    hostname: kafka
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    volumes:
      - ./data/kafka:/bitnami/kafka
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use Confluent instead. https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/quickstart.html Compose - https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/4.0.x/examples/kafka-cluster/docker-compose.yml

Comment: @cricket_007 any pros/cons of the confluent's images vs bitnami's ? Ones I can think of so far: For Bitnami: works straight from the example above. For Confluent: made by the creators of Kafka. Didn't seem as easy (to me) to launch in docker though.